# Phonegap+jquery mobile getLocation

Tags: android, jquery, mobile, cordova, geolocation

Hi basically i have an app that needs to get the current position **every 150 seconds**, im using a chinese tablet with android 2.3 and it **doesn't have gps**, im using only **cell network**.
I've been using this piece of code **inside the deviceready function** to get the current position:

```
 setInterval(
        function(){
            if (navigator.network.connection.type != Connection.NONE && navigator.geolocation) {
                watchID = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                    function(position){
                        plat = position.coords.latitude;
                        plon = position.coords.longitude;
                        console.log('location success');

                        if(map != null){
                            map.setView({center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(plat,plon) });
                            pintaxi.setLocation(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(plat,plon));
                        }
                        count++;
                        if(count == 4){
                            count = 0;
                            console.log('Send data');
                            $.post("http://m2media.mx/plataforma/setpos.php", {latitud: plat, longitud: plon, referencia: 'DEV-008'});
                        }
                   }, 
                   displayError,
                    { timeout: 30000 });
            }
            else{
                if(watchID != null) navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchID);
                console.log('No connection, fail');
            }
        }, 60000
    );
```

Here is the big deal, this app's activity runs at boot, so i have my bootupreceiver like this:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent i = new Intent(context, SmarttaxiActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        context.startActivity(i);
}
```

The problem is that getCurrent position always throw me timeout exception, at first when app boots there **is an interval of about 10 to 20 seconds before 3g is enable**, but even after **3g is enable it stills throw me a timeout exception**, inside the app i have other functions that  use the internet connection like the twitter widget and they run without problem.

The thing is that if I run the app manually after booting the location function works pretty good.
I don't see anything abnormal on the logcat, i've been trying to fix this for three days and still no luck, I hope someone have some ideas of what may be the problem or if the logic im using is wrong.

**Thank you for your time.**

Comment: I am not too sure , but just check if your cordova.js is at the top in index.html. And try that..

Comment: still no luck, but thx for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried **navigator.geolocation.watchPosition** and **navigator.geolocation.clearWatch**..?

navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(success_callback_function, error_callback_function, position_options)

navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watch_position_id)

ok here is example

```
var wpid = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(geo_success, geo_error, {enableHighAccuracy:true, maximumAge:30000, timeout:27000});

function geo_success (position) {

        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var lng = position.coords.longitude;

        //--- your code -- 
}

function geo_error(err) {
         console.log(err);
}
```

---

for clear watchPosition...

```
navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(wpid);
```

Comment: I've tried using watchposition but i have the same issue, maybe is just the network because if i turn on the wifi it works like a charm :(